# Crash dump when closing StoreAppenderContext

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm developing a proof of concept using Chronicle Queue to create a journal. I have just one thread writing and no threads or other processes reading.

During my validations on a 'silent machine', I've came across crash dumps two times.

It's possible to identify that it happens during the close of the StoreAppender$StoreAppenderContext

```
...
siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00007ff267b00010
...
Stack: [0x00007ff394260000,0x00007ff394361000],  sp=0x00007ff39435f630,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 7277 c2 net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.ref.BinaryLongArrayReference.getValueAt(J)J (26 bytes) @ 0x00007ff4011cb523 [0x00007ff4011cb4a0+0x0000000000000083]
j  net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SCQIndexing.setPositionForSequenceNumber(Lnet/openhft/chronicle/queue/impl/ExcerptContext;JJ)V+258
J 5419 c2 net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.StoreAppender$StoreAppenderContext.close(Z)V (638 bytes) @ 0x00007ff400f70448 [0x00007ff400f6fe60+0x00000000000005e8]
...
```

I'am  currently using the version 5.21.99 and planning to upgrade to 5.23.37. I'm usin Java17 last update
This problem happens very rarely (like after days appending) and despite my best efforts I wasn't abble to reproduce it in order to prove that a upgrade to 5.23.37 would fix it.

Can someone confirm if there was any bug fix from  5.21.99 to 5.23.37 that could cause such situation? I've navegated the release notes for hours and I've found nothing.
I've read about a fixed concurrency issue, but given that I have just one thread writing, I think it may not apply to my case.

If you think that it is not related to any previous bugifx, could it be a external processes "touching" the files and causing issues? Any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X.21 had some known issues with Java 17 that were fixed in x.22, which is the first version to support Java 17.

I encourage upgrading to x.23.

Note: the first version to support Java 21 will be x.25.

https://github.com/OpenHFT/OpenHFT/blob/ea/docs/Version-Support.adoc